# Generate multiple datasets according to different variables

Tags: r

I have a number of replicate weightings and I would like to create one dataset per weighting where the weighting multiplies the number of observations by the weighting so the observations in dataset 1 are multiplied by weighting 1. I can do it just not in a very r way.

Here's some data:

```
df <- data.frame(id <- seq(1:100),
             x = rnorm(100), 
        y = x + rnorm(100), 
        X1 = round(runif(100,0,2),0),
        X2 = round(runif(100,0,2),0),
        X3 = round(runif(100,0,2),0),
        X4 = round(runif(100,0,2),0),
        X5 = round(runif(100,0,2),0))
```

and this replicates the observations by the weightings.

```
df1 <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$X1), 1:3]
df2 <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$X2), 1:3]
df3 <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$X3), 1:3]
df4 <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$X4), 1:3]
df5 <- df[rep(row.names(df), df$X5), 1:3]
```

Is it possible to do this in one line - ideally without having to name X each time as there could be lots of Xs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case there are many columns with names that start with 'X' followed by digits, we use `grep` to extract those column names from the original dataset ('df') with the pattern (`^X\\d+`).

```
nm1 <- grep('^X\\d+', names(df), value=TRUE)
```

Then, we loop over the 'nm1', replicate the sequence of rows (`seq_len(nrow(df))`) by the values in the column specified by 'nm1', select the first 3 columns (`1:3`).  The output will be a `list`.

```
lst <- lapply(nm1, function(nm) df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df[,nm]),1:3])
```

In general, it is better to use the `lst` for all the operations as we can do most of the analysis within the `list` environment itself (including exporting the output to files).  But, if we insist to have multiple dataset objects to be shown in the global environment, one option is `list2env` after naming the 'lst' elements with the object names.

```
list2env(setNames(lst, paste0('df', seq_along(lst))), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the reminder, I was writing the description while you commented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation